# CSS flex not separating multiple <div>s

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems using `flex`. I tried to separate some `<div>`s, but the `<div>`s get mixed one on top of each other. I know I can fix it using positioning but I think `flex` is cleaner.

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  border:solid 1px;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  
}


body {
  border:solid 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #0a0a23;
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;}
  nav{
    width:300px;
    height: 100vh;
    border:solid 3px grey;
    border-top:transparent;
    border-left:transparent;
    border-bottom:transparent;
    margin:0px;
    position: fixed;
   
    max-width:800px;
     
      
    
    }
  main{
    border:solid 1px;
    width:calc(100% - 400px);
    padding:0;
    white-space: normal;
 
  position:relative;
  margin:10px 50px;
  
   
  }
```

[image]

I try using space evenly and space around and get worse

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue. As it is, your question has none of the relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be that the `<nav>` and `<main>` elements are set to `position: fixed`, which removes them from the flow of the document and makes them positioned relative to the viewport. To achieve the desired layout using `flex`, you should set the body to `display: flex` and use the `flex` property to specify how the `<nav>` and `<main>` elements should be arranged.

Here's what you can do:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  border: solid 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #0a0a23;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: solid 3px grey;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 800px;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}

main {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  flex: 1;
}
```